# Use PHP to delete duplicate lines within a .txt file

Tags: php, unix, for-loop, fopen

I have multiple txt files with a directory. The text files all contain the same header. I am reading in all the txt files and outputting it all to one file.

Since each individual file contains the same header, It is inserting all of them into the new merged file. How can I remove all the headers in the new merged file and leave one just at the top?

I have been looking at the sort command in unix.

```
sort filename | uniq
```

This command works, but removes all other data that is duplicate. Is there anyway to remove just the specific string "This is a header" but leave one at the top?

**Current Code**

```
$header = array( "XX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-X        XXXXXXXXXXXX" );


$files = glob( "/path/to/folder/*.txt" );

$output_file = "newfile_".date( "YmdHis" ).".txt";

$out = fopen( $output_file, "w" );

foreach( $header as $inputHeader ) {

    fwrite( $out, $inputHeader );
}

    foreach( $files as $file ) {

        $in = fopen( $file, "r" );

            while ( $line = fgets( $in ) ) {

                if( $header !== $line ) {

                    fwrite( $out, $line );

                }

            }

        fclose( $in );

     }

fclose( $out );
```

**The Line that is duplicated many times**
[image: This is the duplicate]

Comment: *"This command works, but removes all other data that is duplicate"* - exactly, thats what the command is supposed to do.  *"Is there anyway to remove just the specific string "This is a header" but leave one at the top?"* Of course, you answered your own question, `uniq` will do that, also : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 1):

Try inputting the header at the start of writing, then check for it later on when you are reading the lines

```
//cache our header lines
$header = "Header line";

$files = glob( "/path/to/files*.txt" );

//print_r($files);

$output_file = "newfile".date( "YmdHis" ).".txt";

$out = fopen( $output_file, "w" );

//input the header line at the top of our new file

fwrite( $out, $header);



foreach( $files as $file ) {

    $in = fopen( $file, "r" );

        while ( $line = fgets( $in ) ) {
            //header check, dont output header lines to new file
            if($header !== preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line)){
                 fwrite( $out, $line );
            }
        }

    fclose( $in );
}

fclose( $out );
```

Comment: After trying this, it stops outputting a file. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: what's the output of running `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your page?

Comment: It dosent give any errors. I changed the $header tag from what you put to the string I am looking for. is that correct?

Comment: is $header still an array? Can you post your new $header tag? (omit personal data if you must)

Comment: Yes, the header tag is still an array. However, I have noticed when I run the script, it gets stuck in a loop somewhere.

Comment: Remove \n\r if you have that in your array

Comment: \n\r is not in the array. The string there is a duplicate of is "TB-CCTDUR035-RMARDTL-T". There are roughly 50 of them in the $output_file. I replaced  $header = array("Line 1 header\n\r","Line 2 header\n\r","Line 3 header\n\r");                                                                        with  $header = array("TB-CCTDUR035-RMARDTL-T"); The array printed out is just  0 => TB-CCTDUR035-RMARDTL-T

Comment: And to be clear. you don't want any of the "TB-CCTDUR035-RMARDTL-T" to output apart from the first line in the header? What does your `newfile+data.txt` file look like?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is no newfile that gets output. The script gets stuck in some sort of loop which prevents a new file from being generated and closed. I cant seem to figure out why. Please check my updated code.

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look at your code when I get back from my lunch, hopefully we can find this pesky bug

Comment: Ok so its no longer in a loop. The file that gets output still contains the duplicates of the header :(

Comment: Its updated, I moved the script to another folder. The first foreach loop works as I commented the rest out and it inputs the header into the $output_file. the second foreach + while loop dosent seem to remove any lines which contain the header.

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer to use just strings instead of Array since you only have 1 header. If that doesn't work then it's because the text of "header" doesn't match with "line". May have to print_r out both and see if they do match.

Comment: This didnt work unfortunately. Please check updated code. I copied the header from the $output _file and pasted it to the $header string in the script. It is an exact match. I ran grep **header** $output_file which returned all the headers that were in the file. So i know that the $header string is correct.

Comment: The $header and $line are not matching up, that's why you are still getting duplicates. Maybe there's some spaces at the end of your $line? see my updated code for a regex to remove white space on $line

Comment: I have tried that also, resulting in the same problem. Seems to be a very weird issue

Answer (score 1):

After you create your new file add this line it will remove duplicated line

```
$lines = array_unique(file("your_file.txt"));
```

Comment: Before fclose and after foreach statement

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix the Issue with help from @WillParky93. I had 4 different headers in the file with duplicates of all of them. after playing around with the logical operators.

**Final Code**

```
//the headers that were in the file with duplicates
$header1 = "DD-LLDRHD045-UHSTAYL-MR        LOCKFMDLA111;
$header2 = "DD-LLDRHD045-UHSTAYL-MR        LOCKFMDLA222";
$header3 = "DD-LLDRHD045-UHSTAYL-MR        LOCKFMDLA333";
$header4 = "DD-LLDRHD045-UHSTAYL-MR        LOCKFMDLA444";

//get all the files to be merged
$files = glob( "/PATH/TO/FILES/*.txt" );

//set the output filename
$output_file = "NewFile".date( "YmdHis" ).".txt";

//open the output file
$out = fopen( $output_file, "w" );

    //loop through the files to be merged
    foreach( $files as $file ) {

        //open each file
        $in = fopen( $file, "r" );

            //while each line in each file
            while ( $line = fgets( $in ) ) {

                //if the current line is not equal to header1, header2, header3 or header4
                if( preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line ) !=
                    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $header1 )&&
                    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line ) !=
                    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $header2 )&&
                    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line ) !=
                    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $header3 )&&
                    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line ) !=
                    preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $header4 ) ) {

                       //write that line to the output file
                       fwrite( $out, $line );

                       //echo $line."\n";

                }else{
                       //write blank line to the file
                       fwrite( $out, "\n" );

                  }

            }
        //close the file
        fclose( $in );

     }
//close the output file
fclose( $out );

//get the contents of the output file
$header1 .= file_get_contents( $output_file );

//add the header to the top of the output file
file_put_contents( $output_file, $header1 );
```

Comment: Nice to see you have fixed your issue! You should consider going back to using an Array now that we knew our headers didn't line up, it will help with readability and give you more flexibility to add/remove headers in the future

Comment: @WillParky93 I shall do that. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

if the file only have 1 header

```
$header_exist = false;

foreach($files as $file) {

  $in = fopen($file, "r");

  while($line = fgets($in)) {
    if(strpos($line, "This is a header") === false) {
      fwrite($out, $line);
    }
    else {
      if($header_exist === false) {
        $header_exist = true;
        fwrite($out, $line);
      }
    }
  }
  fclose($in);
}
```